# Update checkbox value in a Rails index view by using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to apply a small Ajax example in a rails app. I have an items model with checkboxes in the index view. I've created a form_for for the checkbox which I render in the index view. I want to check the checkbox and update the checkbox value in the database.
I'm learning Ajax and I applied some testing by adding the beforeSend and the function(data). From what I read Ajax has POST and GET. If I add type: 'POST' Rails will try to create something, will not find a valid routing path and will error. I want to update the checkbox value in the DB which in Rails is a PUT. How should I proceed? Can you please point me in the right direction?

This is the form I render in the index view.

```
<%= form_for(c, remote: true) do |k| %>
<%= k.check_box :recyclable, :class => "active_testdef_cl", :id => "item_recyclable_#{c.id}", 'data-recyclable' => c.recyclable %>
<% end %>
```

This is the script.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i=0; i < 2; i++ ) {          
             $('#item_recyclable_'+i).on('change', function(){               
             var url='/items'
             var form_data = $('#cc_form').serialize;
             var checkbox_value = $('#item_recyclable_'+i).val();
                  $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: url,                  
                  data: checkbox_value,
                      beforeSend:function(){
                          // $('#test_message').innerHTML=("hello Christina");
                          //alert("hi m")
                      },                 
                    success: function(data) {
                        //$('#test_result').html(data);
                          document.getElementById('test_result').innerHTML=data; 
                    }
              });
              return false;
          });
       };
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restful routing assigns "PUT" and "DELETE" methods to various requests, but in fact these http methods tend to not be used, as many browsers (perhaps just some versions of IE) do not allow them.  So, you're actually only ever sending GET and POST requests.

The workaround for this is to send an extra parameter, `"_method"` (note the underscore) which you would set to "PUT" or "DELETE".  So, if you were to add

```
"_method": "PUT"
```

to your ajax call's data then Rails should process it as a PUT request.  I don't really know what's going on in your ajax as you define form_data and then don't use it.

If you use the `form_for` helper in rails, and it calls the update action, have a look at the rendered-out html in the browser.  You will see a hidden div with an input in it something like this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="_method" value="UPDATE">
</div>
```

This is Rails setting up the workaround for you.  see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

Comment: I was experimenting by checking what comes from form_data and what from checkbox_value.

Comment: Thank you Max. I 'll check it.